# Module not found: Error

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-module

I am currently developping an angular 4 app and i want to use the amexio library.(https://github.com/meta-magic/amexio.github.io).
i installed bootstrap,Requires Tether.js & Popper.js and Font Awesome with NPM.
this is my angular-cli.json styles and script

```
  "styles": [
                "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
                "styles/app.scss",
                "styles.css",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootsrap.css",
                "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awsome.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
                "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
                "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
                "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
```

but when i do npm start i got this error:

```
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css ./src/styles/app.scss ./node_modules/bootsrap/dist/css/bootsrap.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\bootsrap\dist\css\bootsrap.css' in 'D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs'
resolve 'D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\bootsrap\dist\css\bootsrap.css' in 'D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs'
  using description file: D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\@angular\cli\package.json (relative path: ./models/webpack-configs)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\@angular\cli\package.json (relative path: ./models/webpack-configs)
    using description file: D:\workspace\pmnnew\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/bootsrap/dist/css/bootsrap.css)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\bootsrap\dist\css\bootsrap.css doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\bootsrap\dist\css\bootsrap.css.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\bootsrap\dist\css\bootsrap.css.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\bootsrap\dist\css\bootsrap.css doesn't exist
[D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\bootsrap\dist\css\bootsrap.css]
[D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\bootsrap\dist\css\bootsrap.css.ts]
[D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\bootsrap\dist\css\bootsrap.css.js]
[D:\workspace\pmnnew\node_modules\bootsrap\dist\css\bootsrap.css]
 @ multi ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css ./src/styles/app.scss ./node_modules/bootsrap/dist/css/bootsrap.css
```

Comment: font awsome is missing try and install and save it

Comment: i did npm install ... --save

Answer (score 4):

You have imported files with wrong sequence that's why it is giving error. Please follow the sequence that have mentioned.

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "styles/app.scss",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "../src/assets/data/prism/prism.js"
  ],
```